# What is MFC (Microsoft Foundation class Library)?

Tags: mfc

Actually i am unable to understand what actually is MFC?. I have some fair knowledge in C#. When i heard about MFC, i searched in google about that but it is not clear even now. Please explain

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library

Comment: What didn't you understand from (say) Wikipedia?

Comment: Why asp.net tag? MCF is used to built desktop apps and is a GUI library. Also, almost certainly you don't want to use MCF with .NET languages like C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967573.aspx and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library for the details. In general it is a library that wraps portions of the Windows API in C++ classes.